# OnTouch method of OnTouchListener subclass being called many times in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I created a simple `[View.OnTouchListener][1]` implementation in my simple Android app.

My goal right now is to make it detect downward swiping. For example, if I swipe downward, I'd like it to detect that I've done so.

It does this succesfully, however, for each swipe downward, it also gets called a whole bunch of other times. I can see this because of the default behaviour in the `onTouch` methods switch statement:

This is **MySwipeListener**:

```
public class MySwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private Activity activity;

    public MySwipeListener(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.i("MotionEvent", "Action Down!");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Motion Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return true;
            }
            default: {
                Log.i("MotionEvent", "Other Action!");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Other Action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm using it in my `MainActivity`:

```
    Button topUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
    topUp.setOnTouchListener(new MySwipeListener(this));
```

When I physically swipe on my Android screen, I get results like:

```
09-16 16:39:48.276  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Action Down!
09-16 16:39:48.316  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.326  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.346  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.361  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.376  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.396  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.411  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.426  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.446  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.461  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.476  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.496  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.511  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.526  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.546  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.561  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.576  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.596  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.611  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.626  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.631  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.886  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Action Down!
09-16 16:39:48.911  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.926  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.946  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.961  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.976  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:48.996  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.011  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.026  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.046  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.061  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.076  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.096  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.111  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.126  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.146  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.161  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.176  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.196  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.201  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
09-16 16:39:49.206  26748-26748/mobi.corp.proj I/MotionEvent﹕ Other Action!
```

when I'm just expecting a few

```
I/MotionEvent﹕ Action Down!
```

Comment: There could be a misconception: ACTION_DOWN does not refer to the user's finger moving downwards the display, but the user is putting his finger on the display. 

Following ACTION_MOVE events can deliver coordinates, which you should read in order to get the movement vector.

The story ends, when ACTION_UP occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log in the `default` is being printed because when you swipe on the screen `ACTION_MOVE` and probably `ACTION_UP` are called.

If you want to detect a downward swipe you need to get the `y` co-ordinate on `ACTION_DOWN` and compare it to the `y` co-ordinate you get in `ACTION_UP`.

If the `y` in `ACTION_UP` is greater than `ACTION_UP` then there is a downward swipe.

Comment: Why would `ACTION_UP` be called if I'm swiping down only?

Comment: You seem to have some misconception. `ACTION_DOWN` is called when you press your finger on the screen. `ACTION_MOVE` is called after you have pressed the finger and you move it on the screen and `ACTION_UP` is called when you lift the finger up. So when you swipe `ACTION_UP` is called when you lift your finger up after swiping.

Comment: Ah that makes sense actually. That doesn't explain why `ACTION_UP` would be called so many times though for one swipe...

Comment: `ACTION_UP` is not being called. `ACTION_MOVE` is being called many times.

Answer (score 1):

`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is called every time you move your finger an it is  an continuous task. this will be called every pixel it moves. so you may want to exclude  `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` from this class to decrease the noise

Answer (score 0):

You can try a method as seen in [this tutorial](http://eridem.net/android-tip-010-left-and-right-swipe-gesture-events/) to handle swipes.

Ex:

```
// Private class for gestures   
    private class SwipeGestureDetector 
          extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    // Swipe properties, you can change it to make the swipe 
    // longer or shorter and speed
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                         float velocityX, float velocityY) {
      try {
        float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
        float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

        if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
          return false;

        // Left swipe
        if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           YourActivity.this.onLeftSwipe();

        // Right swipe
        } else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
          YourActivity.this.onRightSwipe();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("YourActivity", "Error on gestures");
      }
      return false;
    }
 }

private void onLeftSwipe() {
    // Do something
  }

private void onRightSwipe() {
    // Do something
  }
```